# Merging data frames if value in a variable are different

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I would like to merge two data frames with data from two different sources. The source A includes data from some countries, while the source B includes all countries of source A plus many others. See these data frames as example.

```
dfa<-data.frame("Country"=c("UK","USA","Canada"),"Value"=c(1,2,3),"Source"=c("A","A","A"),"Comments"=c("bla1","bla2","bla3"))
dfb<-data.frame("Country"=c("UK","USA","Canada","France","Germany"),"Value"=c(4,5,6,7,8),"Source"=c("B","B","B","B","B"),"Comments"=c("bla4","bla4","bla5","bla6","bla7"))
```

My goal is to produce in r a merged data frame that contains the rows from data frame A (`dfa`) plus those rows from countries that are located in data frame B (`dfb`) but not in data frame A (`dfa`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dfb %>%
  anti_join(dfa, by = 'Country') %>%
  rbind(dfa)
```

Out:

```
  Country Value Source Comments
1 Germany     8      B     bla7
2  France     7      B     bla6
3      UK     1      A     bla1
4     USA     2      A     bla2
5  Canada     3      A     bla3
```

Answer (score 3):

One way would be this:

```
rbind(dfa, dfb[!dfb$Country %in% dfa$Country, ])
```